# How can I run a PHP counter script when clicking on cetain link?

Tags: php, mysql

I fetching the link from database.

So suppose i have 1000 links from the database.& i want to know which link has click how many times.

So whats should I Do??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create an intermediate pages, taht you link will do the following

1. origine page (where the link is displayed)
2. intermediate page (where you count the click)
3. destination page (where the link you should bring you to)

Link would look like this :
http://mywebsite.tld/link.php?href=http://google.fr
(of course you can and should rewrite url)

EDIT :
As user2912339 said : of course you'll have to keep an entry in database to incremente a number. Unique id could be the URL, a hash, or anything else unique

EDIT2 :
If you want to count click on every distinct links even those which have the same url, I suggest you to go with hash, that way :

1. original page
2. intermediate page (http://mywebsite.tld/link.php?href=a4fd59bcd)
3. retrieve link from database and increment counter
4. destination page

Comment: links bring you from one page to another, and this way you can't count anything using php. What i suggest is that you bring user from one page to an "intermediate page" and there from this intermediate page to the real destination.

Using that way, you can do whatever you want in intermediate page

Answer (score 0):

1) create table link_clicked with columns: id, link, clicked_date

2) create new php file to insert into link_clicked then redirect to the link

Comment: bt the link will be not only 1000 it will be goes on increasing..!!
so the counter should be automatically added

Comment: there is no limit in the database table. it can contain millions, even billions of records, as long as server's memory is enough.